# Displaying information from foreign key relationship to self serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model that contains two foreign keys about the same model. It looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question    = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    parent      = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='parent_comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    grandparent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='grandparent_comment', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    comment     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'd like to create a Comment Serializer that shows parent and grandparent's usernames from the user model. My serializer looks like this:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(source='user')

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```

I know I can do `depth=1` however, that will only display user_id and all the other information about the parent and grandparent comment, but the User information about those two fields. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this,

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer(source='user')
    parent = serializers.CharField(source='parent.user.username', read_only=True, default='')
    grandparent = serializers.CharField(source='grandparent.user.username', read_only=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'
```